# Strange PWM register on PIC

Tags: pic, cpu-registers, pwm

I have to work on some code for a dsPIC33FJ128MC804, and in the PWM library (ad hoc...) there is an assignment to DTCON1. The datasheet, however, doesn't mention this register at all, but only P1DTCON1 and P2DTCON1 for PWM module 1 and 2; nevertheless, in the p33FJ128MC804.h file DTCON1 is defined!
So, the question is: what is this register doing? It controls both PxDTCON1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic name of this register is: `PxDTCON1`: DEAD-TIME CONTROL REGISTER 1.
[Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70291G.pdf) mention it on page 222 section 16-7.

```
The memory address of `DTCON1` = 0x1CC
The memory address of `P1DTCON1` = 0x1CC
The memory address of `P2DTCON1` = 0x5CC
```

The address definition you can find on your disk in file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLAB ASM30 Suite\Support\dsPIC33F\gld\p33FJ128MC804.gld